# How can I show network speed in status bar

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio

How can I show network speed in status bar. I want to show a notification that have a network speed and I achieve it but now I want that to show network speed in status bar like below image.

[image]

All suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot display it in that position. Beyond that, you would need to raise a `Notification` and keep switching the icon based on your detected speed.

Comment: @CommonsWare can you tell me it is possible in flutter? or I have to write the code in native?

Comment: "can you tell me it is possible in flutter?" -- I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: its possible i think, maybe you can set status bar to transparent, create a fake statusbar contain widget you wanna show, its create an illusion

Comment: @SayyidJ but I wanna show it in background 

Comment: you can't display in that position by posting notification, you can add a floating view but it may block status bar